# modifying 'select all' toggle set to 'on' when sub-sliders modified

Tags: toggle, checklist

I'm trying to solve a scenario similar to the checkbox scenario where someone clicks the 'select all' checkbox to check all the options available, then unselects a couple options, turning the 'select all' option from a checkmark to a 'minus sign,' like this:

[image]

What are good approaches to the same exact concept when done with toggles? Maybe just turn the 'all' toggle off, or use a different way to 'select all'?

A quick mockup example:

[image]